# facebook api event feed and comments deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just started with facebook API and can't figure out facebook event feed

so I found in documentation [facebook event/feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/event/feed), but after that, I found [facebook blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/) where it says that feature is deprecated...

but the official documentation doesn't have any note that I can't read feed from it...

as for example, I use Graph API Explorer and I created my private event - for permission I gave it all just to make sure that it's not a permission issue

Will it work if the event is public? or this is deprecated?

EDIT: no its not wirking

example:
event-id 217752602230122

request 217752602230122/feed 217752602230122/comments

will return empty data

but request 217752602230122 will return info about event

```
{
  "description": "testing fb api",
  "end_time": "2020-01-01T15:00:00+0100",
  "name": "Facebook test API",
  "start_time": "2020-01-01T12:00:00+0100",
  "id": "217752602230122"
}
```

Comment: "ill it work?" - why not just try? include your code and/or api calls too.

Comment: @luschn tried, not working... API call is as documentation says... 3.1 -> get -> {event-id}/feed in facebook graph